# Rails rubber deployment on existing EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, rubber

I usually use rubber gem to deploy to Amazon EC2. However, now I want to deploy to an existing EC2 instance which is already running. I could not find any reference on internet. All that I could find uses cap rubber:create_staging or cap rubber:create, but I dont want to create a new instance.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `cap deploy`
As long as your already have your production instance configured, capistrano should deploy the updates.

Comment: hi paul, can you give me few details on how to configure an existing instance to my rails app ?